# fork() and exec() Two Child Processes

Tags: c++, process, fork, exec, parent-child

I am calling fork() twice to create two child processes. I want child process A to do an exec() call and child process B to also do an exec() call. The problem I am having with the given code is that after the first exec() from child process A, the next fork() does not seem to occur and the program exits. I think that it has to do with how exec() overlays the parent process. What I want to accomplish is to call exec() from each of the child processes created by fork().

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

pid_t cpid_a, cpid_b;

cpid_a = fork();
if(cpid_a < 0) {
    std::cout << "Fork failed." << '\n';
    return 1;
}
else if(cpid_a == 0) { // code for child process A
    execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);

    cpid_b = fork();
    if(cpid_b < 0) {
        std::cout << "Fork failed." << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    else if(cpid_b == 0) { // code for child process B
        execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
}
else { // code for parent process
    while(wait(NULL) != -1);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `execlp` returns, it is only because it failed.  You should never have any code after a call to execl that does anything except handle an error.

Comment: IOW, your child should call execl, and the parent should call `fork` a second time.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(cpid_a == 0) { // code for child process A
    execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
```

If this calls succeeds, the following statement, and nothing that follows will ever be executed. That's how `exec()` works. The immediately-following `fork()` never occurs. That's simply how `exec()` works. If `exec()` succeeds, it never returns. The replacement process gets executed in its place.

You even added the 100% correct comment, above: "code for child process A". Everything inside the `if()` statement is "code for child process A", and gets executed when `fork()` returns 0.

You also correctly stated that you want the parent process to fork a second process. Well, you need to have ***that*** code obviously get executed by the parent process, and not the child process:

```
else if(cpid_a == 0) { // code for child process A
    execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    exit(1);
} else {
    cpid_b = fork();

  // The rest of the code.
```

Now, the parent process goes ahead and `fork()` a second time, proceeded on the rest of your plan.

P.S. The `exit()` is just for a good measure. The only time `exec()` returns is when `exec()` fails to execute the given process. Highly unlikely, in the case of `/bin/ls`; if it's missing you have bigger problems to worry about. Still, that's the technically correct thing to do, since continuing execution at that point will result in complete chaos. Again, if `/bin/ls` is missing that's going to be the least of the problems, but this can also happen if, say, the system ran out of memory and can't execute it for that reason; in which case there's no need to add fuel to the fire; but rather have the process die anyway.