# Fork and exec several children in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I want to fork and exec several processes from another.
My parent code is

```
/*Daddy.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
    int main(void)
{
        int status;
        char *nChild;

        for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
            int pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                sprintf(nChild, "%d", i);
                printf("%d\n", i);
                char *const arguments[]={nChild, NULL};
                fflush(NULL);
                execv("child",arguments);
                printf("\nNo , you can't print!\n");
            }else if (pid == -1){
                    printf("%d\n", getpid());
                    exit(0);
            }
        }
        wait(&status);
        printf("Dad %d went out!\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
}
```

and my child process is

```
    /*child.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int args, char **argv){
        if( args !=2){
                printf("Child going away!\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("Child %s: %d going away stylishly!\n", argv[1], getpid());

        exit(0);
}
```

When I don´t create three forks, but one, I know how to create the child, do some work and exit from child and parent. But, in this case, with several children it seems like the child never executes.
Because of the line `wait(&status)` I did hope that when the first child exits, the parent also exits but, any child prints any message.
[Some relevant previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685719/fork-and-exec-two-child-processes) didn´t help.

Comment: can you be more specific with your problem? there several problems with your code, but the worse is probably char *nChild; wich is being written without allocation and shared by children

Comment: Use [waitpid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) instead wait

Comment: **By the way,** I see your some other posts in which there are well answers. **You should accept if an answer is helpful by clicking tick icon on the left side**

Comment: No @snr , the other posts don't resolve the problem because they don't use a for loop in the parent process to create child processes. My problem with that code raises when I use the loop in the loop.

Comment: The problem was no allocation of *nChild. Thanks @OznOg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the job

```
/* daddy.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
        int status=0;
        char nChild[16];
        pid_t wpid;
        for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
            sprintf(nChild, "%d", i);
            int pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", nChild);
                char *const arguments[]={"child", nChild, NULL};
                fflush(NULL);
                execv("child",arguments);
                printf("\nNo , you can't print!\n");
            }else if (pid == -1){
                    printf("%d\n", getpid());
                    exit(0);
            }
        }
        while ((wpid=wait(&status)) >0);
        printf("Dad %d went out!\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
}
```

As @OnzOg said in the comments of the question, allocation of `nChild` was the main problem. Also `execv` need pass child name twice, one as argument.
And finally, to improve the code, parent process needs to wait all processes to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make parent wait for all child processes to finish. If not, assume that 1 child waited for is done and then parent exits. What about the other 2 children? They become orphan since their parent doesn't wait for them.

```
pid_t wpid;
int status = 0;
.
.
while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0); // the parent waits for all the child processes
```